# jQuery - On change with multiple conditions

Tags: jquery

I want to hide all of the items that have been submitted to simulate only showing items that currently need an upload (hiding archived items).

I only want to have the items `show/hide` depending on whether the checkbox is checked.

What I need: If a file is uploaded and submit is pressed -> and if the checkbox is check -> hide the item that has been submitted. If the checkbox is not checked when a file is uploaded and submit is pressed, then don't hide the item until the checkbox is checked at some point.

```js
function count() {
  var x = $(".item:not(.archive)").length;
  $("#count").text(x);
}
count();
$("#state").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    if ($(".item").hasClass("archive")) {
      $(".item.archive").addClass("hidden");
    }
  } else {
    $(".item.archive").removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  var $uploader = $(this).closest(".item").find("input");
  if ($uploader.val() !== "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("background-color", "#4dcb83");
    $(this).html("Archived");
    $(this).closest(".item").addClass("hidden");
    $(this).closest(".item").addClass("archive");
    $uploader.val("");
    count();
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 12px 12px
}

#count {
  margin-left: 6px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  outstanding:
  <div id="count">0</div>
</div>
<label for="state">
  <input id="state" type="checkbox">
  Hide Archived?
</label>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="file">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="file">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding What is the problem you are having :)  meaning what does not work in this example you have added in the question ?

Comment: The items are being hidden when submit button is pressed but isn't linked to the state of the checkbox to only hide if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the question by creating a function to handle the state of the items and calling it when I submit the item.

In this function I check if the item has been given the archive class and find the state of the checkbox.

```js
function archive() {
  var x = $(".item:not(.archive)").length;
  $("#count").text(x);
  if ($(".item").hasClass("archive") && $("#state").is(":checked")) {
    $(".item.archive").addClass("hidden");
  }
  $("#state").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      if ($(".item").hasClass("archive")) {
        $(".item.archive").addClass("hidden");
      }
    } else {
      $(".item.archive").removeClass("hidden");
    }
  });
}
archive();
$(document).on("click", "button", function (e) {
  var $uploader = $(this).closest(".item").find("input");
  if ($uploader.val() !== "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("background-color", "#4dcb83");
    $(this).html("Sent");

    $(this).closest(".item").addClass("archive");
    $uploader.val("");
    archive();
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="count">0</div>
<label for="state">
  <input id="state" type="checkbox" checked>
  Hide?
</label>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="file">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="file">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was about to post something similar. Glad all is working for you.